# Regex matching broadly after first match

Tags: regex

I've got the following regex

```
<\?php\n//{{([^*]|[\r\n])*\?>
```

To match the following

```
<?php
//{{
...
?>
```

The problem is, once the regex matches this, it'll match the following

```
<?php
...
?>
```

So basically, once it matches the //{{ it'll match any php tag after.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your regex correctly, but you can try a non-greedy solution:

```
<\?php\n//{{([^*]|[\r\n])*?\?>
```

Just append ? to the *.